# Use of table valued function in order by clause

Tags: sql-server

Can I use my table valued function in order by clause of my select query????

Like this :

```
declare @ID int
set @ID=9011
Exec ('select top 10 * from cs_posts order by ' + (select * from dbo.gettopposter(@ID)) desc)
```

GetTopPoster(ID) is my table valued function.

Please help me on this.

Comment: You are trying to concatenate the result of a select to a string? How is that supposed to work?

Comment: have you tried your code? if yes any `errors` you are getting.

Comment: if select * returns more than one result, It won't work.

Comment: Rakesh, could you describe the objective of your query?

Comment: I am getting this error 
'Incorrect syntax near 'GetTopPoster'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a table-valued function with a `join`.  That also allows you to choose any combination of columns to sort by:

```
select  top 10 * 
from    cs_posts p
join    dbo.gettopposter(@ID) as gtp
on      p.poster_id = gtp.poster_id
order by
        gtp.col1
,       gtp.col2
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use a Table Valued Function just as a normal table.

Your query is not valid SQL though, despite the TVF.

For further reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like that - how does it know what to order by? It doesn't know how the TVF relates to the original query. You can join the two however (as I assume cs_posts has an id column which relates to the TVF) and then order by the the TVF id column.